# Create 2x2 groupplot with +1 plot to the side?

Tags: pgfplots, subfloats, groupplots

I want to create a 2x2 + 1 plot like...

```
---------------------------|
| Plot 1 | Plot 2 |        |
------------------- Plot 5 | 
| Plot 3 | Plot 4 |        |
---------------------------|
```

How can I achieve that? With the pgfplots package?

Comment: Can you post a dummy example for the plots? It's really not fun to write up 5 sub plots from scratch.

Comment: Yeah for some reason I was only thinking in groupplots but subfigure is a much better solution since they indeed don't have the same caption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's something to get you started

[image: screenshot]

I have used the [`subcaption`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/subcaption) package which provides, among other things, the `subfigure` environment. You can think of this as a `minipage`- it takes all of the same mandatory and optional arguments.

Adjust the widths as you like :)

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\pgfplotsset{
    every axis/.append style={
        scale only axis,       
        width=\textwidth,
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}%
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
        \begin{subfigure}{.4\textwidth}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}
                    \addplot {x^2};
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption{}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}{.4\textwidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}
                    \addplot {x^2};
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption{}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \\
        \begin{subfigure}{.4\textwidth}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}
                    \addplot {x^2};
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption{}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}{.4\textwidth}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}
                    \addplot {x^2};
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption{}
        \end{subfigure}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
        \begin{subfigure}{.9\textwidth}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}
                    \addplot {x^2};
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption{}
        \end{subfigure}
    \end{minipage}%
    \caption{}%
    \label{}%
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need a separate caption, it's just as simple as add an `axis` after the `groupplot` and offset it appropriately.

Below, I added an extra axis to the manual's `groupplot` example.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{
        every axis/.append style={
            scale only axis,
            xmin=0, xmax=2,
            ymin=0, ymax=2,
            xtick distance=1,
            ytick distance=1,
            enlarge x limits=true,
            enlarge y limits=true,
        }
    }
\def\sep{0.5cm}
\def\side{1.5cm}
    \begin{groupplot}[
        group style={
            group name=small, % so that plots' coords can be ref'd
            group size=2 by 2,
            x descriptions at=edge bottom,
            y descriptions at=edge left,
            horizontal sep=\sep,
            vertical sep=\sep,
        },
        height=\side,
        width=\side,
    ]
        \nextgroupplot
        \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,2)};
        \nextgroupplot
        \addplot coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (2,0)};
        \nextgroupplot[
            ylabel=$y$ label,
            y label style={at=(ticklabel cs:1.15)},
        ]
        \addplot coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (2,1)};
        \nextgroupplot[
            xlabel=$x$ label,
            x label style={at=(ticklabel cs:0.85)},
        ]
        \addplot coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (1,0)};
    \end{groupplot}

    \begin{axis}[
        name=big,
        at={($(small c2r2.south east)+(\sep+2ex,0)$)}, % offset
        height=\side*2+\sep,
        width=\side*2+\sep,
    ]
        \addplot coordinates {(0,1.5) (1,0.5) (2,1.5)};

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]