# Create groupplot 3 x 6

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, groupplots

I asked a similar question before: [Create 2x2 groupplot with +1 plot to the side?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117678/create-2x2-groupplot-with-1-plot-to-the-side)

For that time using the subfigure environment wasn't a problem. But I do not want to use the subfigure environment now, so I am looking for a different solution. The plot I want to create is:

```
|-----------------|
|        | Plot 4 |
| Plot 1 |--------| 
|        | Plot 5 |
|-----------------|
|        | Plot 6 |
| Plot 2 |--------| 
|        | Plot 7 |
|-----------------|
|        | Plot 8 |
| Plot 3 |--------| 
|        | Plot 9 |
|-----------------|
```

Plot 1,2,3 have namely the same x-axis (and for those interested it is a impulse response plot), as well as the plots 4,..,9 (which are bode plots, magnitude + phase).

Does anyone have any idea? I think groupplots should be extend to have some tabular capabilities.

If you are looking for a minimal example I don't have really one since I do not know how to create this but the code of the solution of my previous question might get you started, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/117685/15360

ps. btw the solution does not necessarly have to be using the groupplot environment. The main reason I use groupplot very often because I know then that the alignment is good. Also when you show the x- and ylabels aswell as the ticks of x and y. So it is meanly about that the alignment is correct.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use two `groupplots` environments, where the height of the axes in the second is half that of the first. To align them properly I placed the first sub-plot of the second groupplot relative to the first groupplot, with

```
\nextgroupplot[anchor=north west, at={($(left plots c1r1.north east) + (0.2cm,0)$)}]
```

`left plots` is a label for the first groupplot, added with

```
group style={
   group name=left plots,
   ..
   }
```

and `left plots c1r1` is the axis that is in the first column and first row of the group.

I used the `($(a) + (b)$)` syntax from the `calc` library as `([xshift=0.2cm]left plots c1r1.north east)` didn't work.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
   group style={
      group name=left plots,
      group size=1 by 3,
      vertical sep=0pt,
      x descriptions at=edge bottom},
   width=4cm,
   height=4cm,
   scale only axis]
\nextgroupplot
 \addplot {x^2};
\nextgroupplot
 \addplot {x^2};
 \nextgroupplot
 \addplot {x^2};
\end{groupplot}

\begin{groupplot}[
    group style={
       group size=1 by 6,
       vertical sep=0pt,
       x descriptions at=edge bottom},
    width=4cm,
    height=2cm,
    scale only axis,
    ytick pos=right]
\nextgroupplot[anchor=north west, at={($(left plots c1r1.north east) + (0.2cm,0)$)}]
 \addplot {sqrt(x)};
\nextgroupplot
 \addplot {sqrt(x)};
 \nextgroupplot
 \addplot {sqrt(x)};
\nextgroupplot
 \addplot {sqrt(x)};
\nextgroupplot
 \addplot {sqrt(x)};
 \nextgroupplot
 \addplot {sqrt(x};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

## Old answer

I would like a `groupplots` only solution, but a workaround is to use two `tikzpicture`s each having a `groupplot` environment, where the height of the axes in the second is half the height of those in the first.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
   group style={
      group size=1 by 3,
      vertical sep=0pt,
      x descriptions at=edge bottom},
   width=4cm,
   height=4cm,
   scale only axis]
\nextgroupplot
 \addplot {x^2};
\nextgroupplot
 \addplot {x^2};
 \nextgroupplot
 \addplot {x^2};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
    group style={
       group size=1 by 6,
       vertical sep=0pt,
       x descriptions at=edge bottom},
    width=4cm,
    height=2cm,
    scale only axis,
    ytick pos=right]
\nextgroupplot
 \addplot {sqrt(x)};
\nextgroupplot
 \addplot {sqrt(x)};
 \nextgroupplot
 \addplot {sqrt(x)};
\nextgroupplot
 \addplot {sqrt(x)};
\nextgroupplot
 \addplot {sqrt(x)};
 \nextgroupplot
 \addplot {sqrt(x};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to do this inside a single 2x6 grouplot by grouping 2 by 2 the graphs of the left column:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \pgfplotsset{
      % override style for non-boxed plots
          % which is the case for both sub-plots
    every non boxed x axis/.style={},
    rightGraph/.style={ytick pos=right},
    leftUpperGraph/.style={ axis x line=top, ymin=10,ymax=20, xmin=-5,xmax=5, ytick={12,14,...,18}, %To remove one of the two 10 so it doesn't look bold.
  },
    leftLowerGraph/.style={ axis x line=bottom, ymin=0,ymax=10, xmin=-5,xmax=5,}, 
  }
  \begin{groupplot}[
      group style={
        group size=2 by 6,
        vertical sep=0pt,
        horizontal sep=2mm,
      x descriptions at=edge bottom},
      width=4cm,
      height=2cm,
    scale only axis]
    \nextgroupplot[%
      leftUpperGraph,
    ]
    \addplot {x^2};
    \nextgroupplot[%
      rightGraph,
    ]
    \addplot {sqrt(x)};
    \nextgroupplot[%
      leftLowerGraph,
    ]
    \addplot {x^2};
    \nextgroupplot[%
      rightGraph,
    ]
    \addplot {sqrt(x)};
    \nextgroupplot[%
      leftUpperGraph,
    ]
    \addplot {x^2};
    \nextgroupplot[%
      rightGraph,
    ]
    \addplot {sqrt(x)};
    \nextgroupplot[%
      leftLowerGraph,
    ]
    \addplot {x^2};
    \nextgroupplot[%
      rightGraph,
    ]
    \addplot {sqrt(x)};
    \nextgroupplot[%
      leftUpperGraph,
    ]
    \addplot {x^2};
    \nextgroupplot[%
      rightGraph,
    ]
    \addplot {sqrt(x)};
    \nextgroupplot[%
      leftLowerGraph,
    ]
    \addplot {x^2};
    \nextgroupplot[%
      rightGraph,
    ]
    \addplot {sqrt(x)};
     \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I haven't write any groupplots in months (other than this one^^) so I have a bonus question: how can I define a style for a groupplot, `\tikzstyle` doesn't work… This would make my code a bit shorter :)

#### Edit:

An answer have be given by Torbjørn T. so I updated my answer accordingly introducing styles.

[image: The proposed solution]

Comment: You can use e.g. `mygroupstyle/.style={ytick pos=right}` inside `\pgfplotsset`. Using `\tikzstyle` is, I think, discouraged in favour of `\tikzset{stylename/.style={}}` anyway.

Comment: @torbjørn-t thanks, I've updated my answer accordingly.