# Creating a non-standard array of plots

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to make a plot using pgfplots that has two columns the first has three plots and the second column only has a single plot. After looking online and at the docs for group-plots, I surprisingly did not find anything. I was thinking I could make a nested groupplot, but I wanted to see if there is a better way first. Any thoughts?

Comment: possible solution: four in depended plots, three plots on one `minipage`, the fourth in second. welcome to tex.se!

Comment: Can you even nest groupplots? I'd use a groupplot for the first column, and a normal `axis` for the second, placed relative to the group. Kind of similar to the first code in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150980/create-groupplot-3-x-6/150997#150997

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Zarko thank you for the suggestion!

Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass[draft=on]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[group style={group name = myplot, group size = 1 by 4},height = 5cm, width = \linewidth]

\nextgroupplot[]
\addplot[domain=-2*pi:2*pi, samples=100]{cos(deg(x))};

\nextgroupplot[]
\addplot[domain=-2*pi:2*pi, samples=100]{cos(deg(x))};

\nextgroupplot[]
\addplot[domain=-2*pi:2*pi, samples=100]{cos(deg(x))};

\nextgroupplot[]
\addplot[domain=-2*pi:2*pi, samples=100]{cos(deg(x))};

\end{groupplot}  % end

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}% Do not skip a line between minipages. Otherwise, it will place the figures one below the other.
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[height = 18cm, width = \linewidth]           
\addplot[domain=-2*pi:2*pi, samples=100]{cos(deg(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

which produces this [image]

Comment: you are welcome! you can accept own answer!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a variant using just one `tikzpicture`, including some trickery to calculate the total height of the first four plots, and using that height for the last `axis`. The benefit of this is that you ensure that the top of the axis in the second column is aligned with the top of the first axis in the first column, and the bottom with the bottom of the last axis in the first column.

```
\documentclass[draft=on]{scrbook}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} % required for the let syntax
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
  group style={
    group name = myplot,
    group size = 1 by 4
  },
  height = 5cm,
  width = 0.45\linewidth]

\nextgroupplot[]
\addplot[domain=-2*pi:2*pi, samples=100]{cos(deg(x))};

\nextgroupplot[]
\addplot[domain=-2*pi:2*pi, samples=100]{cos(deg(x))};

\nextgroupplot[]
\addplot[domain=-2*pi:2*pi, samples=100]{cos(deg(x))};

\nextgroupplot[]
\addplot[domain=-2*pi:2*pi, samples=100]{cos(deg(x))};

\end{groupplot}  % end

% specify coordinate for top left of axis in second column
\coordinate (col2) at ([xshift=1.5cm]myplot c1r1.north east);
% calculate height of big axis
\path
let
\p1=(myplot c1r1.north), \p2=(myplot c1r4.south), \n1={\y1-\y2}
in
\pgfextra{%
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\tmp}{\n1}
\global\let\totalplotheight\tmp
};

\begin{axis}[
  at=(col2),
  % default anchor for axis is south west, we want north west
  anchor=north west,
  % we want the height to apply only to the axis box, not including labels, so add scale only axis
  scale only axis, 
  height = \totalplotheight,
  width = 0.45\linewidth
]           
\addplot[domain=-2*pi:2*pi, samples=100]{cos(deg(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]