# Matplotlib's GridSpec in PGFPlots

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots, grids

I'm looking how to have the following layout in PGFPlots:

[image]

This can be achieved using `gridspec` in `matplotlib`, but I can't find a way to do the same using `groupplots` (there doesn't seem to be any info about this in the manual).

I found this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150980/create-groupplot-3-x-6), but it is somewhat hacky and the spacing between plots is off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it using `\nextgroupplot[group/empty plot]`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=3 by 2, horizontal sep=4em}]
            \nextgroupplot[
                width=7.5cm,
                height=7.5cm,
                xlabel=$x$,
                ylabel={$f(x) = x^2 - x +4$}
                ]
                \addplot {x^2 - x +4};

            \nextgroupplot[
                width=7.5cm,
                height=7.5cm,
                xlabel=$x$,
                ylabel={$f(x) = x^2 - x +4$}
                ]
                \addplot {x^2 - x +4};

            \nextgroupplot[
                width=7.5cm,
                height=7.5cm,
                xlabel=$x$,
                ylabel={$f(x) = x^2 - x +4$}
                ]
                \addplot {x^2 - x +4};

            \nextgroupplot[group/empty plot]

            \nextgroupplot[
                width=3 * 7.4cm,
                height=7.5cm,
                xlabel=$x$,
                ylabel={$f(x) = x^2 - x +4$}
                ]
                \addplot {x^2 - x +4};

            \nextgroupplot[group/empty plot]
        \end{groupplot}     
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This yields
[image]