# Create 2x2 array of 3D plots with pgfplots. Running into compiling issues

Tags: pgfplots, 3d, groupplots

I'm plotting one function of three variables as four functions of two variables, with each of the four plots having the third variable fixed at a particular value. 
An example is below:
[image: A function in 3D space, it is almost a flat plane angled at 25 degrees, however curves very slighty downward at the origin, and has a slight rise in the middle of the plot]

For anyone interested, It's source code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
name=axis1,
grid=major,
view={35}{45},
]
\addplot3+ [
mesh,
scatter,
faceted color=blue,
samples=10,
domain=0:100,y domain=0:100
] {0.1667*(x*y)^(0.5) + (0.5)*(x)^(0.5) + (0.5)*(y)^(0.5) + (0.5)*(x*y)^(0.5) + x + y + 1 };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

**I'm aiming to have a 2x2 array/grid of these four plots. I'm not sure "minipage" is  a good idea here, but it's the approach I've been taking.**

I'd also like to set the z-axis to a particular value (500) to make the comparison between these 2-variable functions clearer, however I may save that for another question (if I get an answer here, I'd still like to ask it as a question so others may find it).

Individually my plots compile fine, however when embedded into the figure and minipage environments, LaTeX doesn't return anything nice.

Here's the source code I've got so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}


\section{Plot with one variable held constant}

Consider $A(x,y,z)$ for a particular value of z:
$$ \mathfrak{A} = \frac{\sqrt{x y z}}{6} + \frac{\sqrt{x y} + \sqrt{y z} + \sqrt{x z}}{2} + x + y + z $$

$$For z = 1:$$

$$For z = 10$$


$$For z = 20:$$

$$For z = 30:$$

\begin{figure}%
\begin{minipage}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
name=axis1,
grid=major,
view={35}{45},
]
\addplot3+ [
mesh,
scatter,
faceted color=blue,
samples=10,
domain=0:100,y domain=0:100
] {0.1667*(x*y)^(0.5) + (0.5)*(x)^(0.5) + (0.5)*(y)^(0.5) + (0.5)*(x*y)^(0.5) + x + y + 1 };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\centering
\begin{subfigure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
name=axis2,
grid=major,
view={35}{45},
]
\addplot3+ [
mesh,
scatter,
faceted color=blue,
samples=10,
domain=0:100,y domain=0:100
] {0.1667*(10*x*y)^(0.5) + (0.5)*(10*x)^(0.5) + (0.5)*(10*y)^(0.5) + (0.5)*(x*y)^(0.5) + x + y + 10 };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\centering
\begin{subfigure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
name=axis3,
grid=major,
view={35}{45},
]
\addplot3+ [
mesh,
scatter,
faceted color=blue,
samples=10,
domain=0:100,y domain=0:100
] {0.1667*(20*x*y)^(0.5) + (0.5)*(20*x)^(0.5) + (0.5)*(20*y)^(0.5) + (0.5)*(x*y)^(0.5) + x + y + 20 };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}%
\\
\centering
\begin{subfigure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
name=axis4,
grid=major,
view={35}{45},
]
\addplot3+ [
mesh,
scatter,
faceted color=blue,
samples=10,
domain=0:100,y domain=0:100
] {0.1667*(30*x*y)^(0.5) + (0.5)*(30*x)^(0.5) + (0.5)*(30*y)^(0.5) + (0.5)*(x*y)^(0.5) + x + y + 30 };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\end{minipage}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was largely copying from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117678/create-2x2-groupplot-with-1-plot-to-the-side w.r.t. the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two proposals, either subfigures in tabular or just a Ti*k*Zy matrix.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}


\section{Plot with one variable held constant}

% Consider $A(x,y,z)$ for a particular value of z:
% \[ \mathfrak{A} = \frac{\sqrt{x y z}}{6} + \frac{\sqrt{x y} + \sqrt{y z} +
% \sqrt{x z}}{2} + x + y + z \]
% 
% \[For z = 1:\]
% 
% \[For z = 10\]
% 
% 
% \[For z = 20:\]
% 
% \[For z = 30:\]

\begin{figure}[htb]%
\pgfplotsset{width=0.9\linewidth,zmax=500}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
name=axis1,
grid=major,
view={35}{45},
]
\addplot3+ [
mesh,
scatter,
faceted color=blue,
samples=10,
domain=0:100,y domain=0:100
] {0.1667*(x*y)^(0.5) + (0.5)*(x)^(0.5) + (0.5)*(y)^(0.5) + (0.5)*(x*y)^(0.5) + x + y + 1 };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}% 
& 
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
name=axis2,
grid=major,
view={35}{45},
]
\addplot3+ [
mesh,
scatter,
faceted color=blue,
samples=10,
domain=0:100,y domain=0:100
] {0.1667*(10*x*y)^(0.5) + (0.5)*(10*x)^(0.5) + (0.5)*(10*y)^(0.5) + (0.5)*(x*y)^(0.5) + x + y + 10 };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure} \\
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
name=axis3,
grid=major,
view={35}{45},
]
\addplot3+ [
mesh,
scatter,
faceted color=blue,
samples=10,
domain=0:100,y domain=0:100
] {0.1667*(20*x*y)^(0.5) + (0.5)*(20*x)^(0.5) + (0.5)*(20*y)^(0.5) + (0.5)*(x*y)^(0.5) + x + y + 20 };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}%
&
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
name=axis4,
grid=major,
view={35}{45},
]
\addplot3+ [
mesh,
scatter,
faceted color=blue,
samples=10,
domain=0:100,y domain=0:100
] {0.1667*(30*x*y)^(0.5) + (0.5)*(30*x)^(0.5) + (0.5)*(30*y)^(0.5) + (0.5)*(x*y)^(0.5) + x + y + 30 };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}%
\end{tabular}
\caption{With subfigures from the \texttt{subcation} package.}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[htb]%
\pgfplotsset{width=0.45\linewidth,zmax=500}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix{
\begin{axis}[
name=axis1,
grid=major,
view={35}{45},
]
\addplot3+ [
mesh,
scatter,
faceted color=blue,
samples=10,
domain=0:100,y domain=0:100
] {0.1667*(x*y)^(0.5) + (0.5)*(x)^(0.5) + (0.5)*(y)^(0.5) + (0.5)*(x*y)^(0.5) + x + y + 1 };
\end{axis}
&
\begin{axis}[
name=axis2,
grid=major,
view={35}{45},
]
\addplot3+ [
mesh,
scatter,
faceted color=blue,
samples=10,
domain=0:100,y domain=0:100
] {0.1667*(10*x*y)^(0.5) + (0.5)*(10*x)^(0.5) + (0.5)*(10*y)^(0.5) + (0.5)*(x*y)^(0.5) + x + y + 10 };
\end{axis} \\
\begin{axis}[
name=axis3,
grid=major,
view={35}{45},
]
\addplot3+ [
mesh,
scatter,
faceted color=blue,
samples=10,
domain=0:100,y domain=0:100
] {0.1667*(20*x*y)^(0.5) + (0.5)*(20*x)^(0.5) + (0.5)*(20*y)^(0.5) + (0.5)*(x*y)^(0.5) + x + y + 20 };
\end{axis}
&
\begin{axis}[
name=axis4,
grid=major,
view={35}{45},
]
\addplot3+ [
mesh,
scatter,
faceted color=blue,
samples=10,
domain=0:100,y domain=0:100
] {0.1667*(30*x*y)^(0.5) + (0.5)*(30*x)^(0.5) + (0.5)*(30*y)^(0.5) + (0.5)*(x*y)^(0.5) + x + y + 30 };
\end{axis}\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{With a \texttt{tikz} matrix.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

BTW, your example did not compile because you have not loaded the relevant packages in the preamble, and `$$ ... $$` is to be replaced by `\[ ... \]`.